# What's a common approach iOS apps use to allow users to export their textual data?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

I'm diving into iOS development. I am building a simple Diary app.  I'd like to be able to export my data somehow to my other computers.  What are some common, simple steps to export plain textual data?

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few options spring to mind.

- Give the option to email it
- Utilise 3.2/4.0's file sharing APIs to allow access to documents created within the app via iTunes
- Upload to a webservice

I'm sure there are more, but that's what I immediately thought of.